# Can I convert my Visual C++ win32 project into a crossplatform later?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

does anybody know if it is possible to use the code from a win32 static libary 
in a cross platform one? I know i have to make some changes to the code but i think c++ code is the same on all platforms except for the classes. For simple types somebody told me to use the int16_t or int16_fast_t instead or short for example. Is that correct that i could just copy ally the headers and files from visual studio and compile them for mac with for example code lite - if code itself is crossplatform?

Best Regards,

K

Comment: Be careful not to call any OS specific functions.

Comment: It would be a good idea to define your own types (or at least type alias) serving specific purpose instead of generic int16_t. As for question itself, it is not clear why are you calling your library "win32", it code is the same on all platforms, then it is platform-independent, if it is not - then you can extract platform depended parts and implement them differently on different platforms.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to know - i can reuse code. Pls write an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's in that library. The fact that it's a Visual C++ Win32 static library project tells us how your library is compiled. It does not tell us anything about what code goes into that library. It might be all perfectly portable Standard C++ code. It might as well be code where every second line is a Windows API function call that will obviously not be portable.

Whether or not the code of a library will be portable all depends on the code. Replacing `short` with `int16_t` or `int_fast16_t` will do nothing to increase the portability of code (unless the original use of `short` assumed some implementation-defined properties). So I'm not sure what a blanket replacement of `short` with `int16_t` is supposed to achieve. `short` is a fundamental type built into the language. `int16_t` is a type defined by the standard library *if* the target platform supports it. So, in a way, `int16_t` is actually less portable than `short`. While `int_fast16_t` is always defined, so is `short`. Use the fixed-width integer types of the standard library if you need the semantics that they provide. If you don't then there's no reason to use them. Note that to use the fixed-width integer types in C++, include the C++ header `<cstdint>` rather than `<stdint.h>` which is not guaranteed to be present in C++. Also note that `<cstdint>` is only guaranteed to place declarations in namespace `std`. So for maximum portability, use `std::int16_t` because it is not guaranteed that `::int16_t` is available.

If the code of the library is portable, then all you will need to build that library on another platform is a buildsystem for that platform. So yes, it is correct that if the code is portable, all you need to do is compile that code on the other platform using whatever tools you use on that other platform…that's kind of the very definition of what it means for code to be portable… ;-)